# Кодировка сообщения в JSON

Tags: php, json

Я сделал обработчик платежей для UnitPay на Php, и в какой-то момент он перестал работать, написал в поддержку UnitPay и они ответили, что сообщение для ответа не кодируется в json, можете помочь? Сам код

```
<?php
define("TKM", true);
require(realpath("../../system.php"));

function upSign($method, $params, $secretKey) {
    ksort($params);
    unset($params['sign']);
    unset($params['signature']);
    array_push($params, $secretKey);
    array_unshift($params, $method);

    return hash('sha256', join('{up}', $params));
}

$method = $_GET['method'];
$params = $_GET['params'];

if ($params['signature'] != upSign($method, $params, $unitpay['settings']['secret_key'])) {
    exit('{"error": {"message": "Некорректная цифровая подпись"}}');
}

if ($method != 'pay') {
    exit('{"result": {"message":"Запрос успешно обработан [actionCheck]"}}');
}

$payment = new Payment;
$status = $payment->select($_GET['params']['account'], $params['orderSum']);

if ($status !== true) {
    exit('{"error": {"message": "{' . $status . '}"}}');
}

$status = $payment->give();

if ($status !== true) {
    exit('{"error": {"message": "{' . $status . '}"}}');
}

exit('{"result": {"message":"Запрос успешно обработан [actionPay]"}}');
```

Comment: начните с того, чтобы формировать json не руками, а предназначенными для этого функцией. И замените exit на echo, который все же больше предназначен для вывода. А еще снабдите ответ сервера заголовками типа контента.

Comment: @teran, если не секрет, то как это сделать, я не особо в этом разбираюсь, вообще мне помогали писать этот код